# Strict Operator essential in PHP 7.3 but not in PHP 7.2

Tags: php, migration, drupal-8, php-7.2, php-7.3

I've used this page as a reference to see the changelog notes for migrating from [PHP 7.2 to 7.3](https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration73.php), but what I'm unable to find there is a reference of the strict operator or `===`.

The issue is that one of my projects, the below code was working fine without any error when my project was on PHP 7.2 but when I migrated to PHP 7.3, everything works fine except this code

```
if ($a == $b)
```

This is throwing an error

```
Fatal error: Nesting level too deep - recursive dependency?
```

which is fixed by using

```
if ($a === $b)
```

wherein in both the above examples, `$a` & `$b` are derived from [FieldItemList](https://api.drupal.org/FieldItemList) but I'm not sure if it's mentioned somewhere within the migration guidelines which I could have missed?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and include the complete error message as  well as example of the data in the variables that causes the error.

Answer (score 0):

Manual at https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.object-comparison.php says:

> When using the comparison operator (==), object variables are compared
>   in a simple manner, namely: Two object instances are equal if they
>   have the same attributes and values (values are compared with ==), and
>   are instances of the same class.
>
> When using the identity operator (===), object variables are identical
>   if and only if they refer to the same instance of the same class.

It means that if your FieldItemList::$parent points to itself, `==` operator end in recursion as that is circular refercnce. `===` operator only checks identity and does not investigate the properties of the object, therefore does not end in infinite recursion.

I don't know why should migration of PHP cause this. Maybe migration was one of the changes and the problem lies somewhere else?

Comment: That's what the interesting part is, I'm unable to understand how the same code is working without any issue if I'm toggling my PHP version to 7.2 :|